# Linq - cast anonymous type to concrete type

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I'm working with the following linq statement:

```
        var suppliers = SupplierView.Select()
            .GroupBy(x => x.Name.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper(),
                (alphanumeric, suppliers) => new
                {
                    Alphanumeric = alphanumeric,
                    Suppliers = suppliers.OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList()
                })
            .OrderBy(x => x.Alphanumeric);
```

I'd like to return this from a method, however to do so I beleiev i'll need to use a concrete type rather an anonymous type.

Here's the concrete type:

```
public class AlphanumericSuppliers
{
    public string Alphanumeric { get; set; }
    public IOrderedEnumerable<Supplier> Suppliers { get; set; }
}
```

However, I'm having difficulty getting the correct syntax to convert the anonymous type to my concrete type.

Anyone advise?

Comment: so you know how to create an anonymous type but you don't know how to create an instance of a named type, seriously.... ?

Comment: I know how to do it as per the code below which I have, but it gives me syntax errors.

Comment: then you should have included the error messages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply create instances of the concrete type (there is no requirement to use an anonymous types in LINQ):

```
var suppliers = SupplierView.Select()
        .GroupBy(x => x.Name.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper(),
            (alphanumeric, suppliers) => new AlphanumericSuppliers // concrete
            {
                Alphanumeric = alphanumeric,
                Suppliers = suppliers.OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList() // *
            })
        .OrderBy(x => x.Alphanumeric);
```

<sub><sup>*As mentioned in comments, either change `Suppliers` to be `IEnumerable<Supplier>` or remove the `ToList` call from here</sup></sub>

Comment: won't compile unless you change the type of Suppliers.

Comment: @Selman22 True. Or I think removing the `ToList` call will work.

Comment: @Selman22 - you have the correct answer - please post an answer if you want me to select an answer.