# Unable to cast IEnumerable to specified type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, collections, anonymous-types

I have an object called **ComicBookRepository** which contains a list (**_comicBooks**) of type **ComicBook**.

As part of this implementation, I have a method called **GetComicBook()** with a single parameter 'Id' of type **int** that returns a **ComicBook** whos Id property matches the int parameter passed in.

```
ComicBook comicBook = null;

foreach (var book in _comicBooks)
{
    if (book.Id == id)
    {
        comicBook = book;
        break;
    }
}

return comicBook;
```

I am trying to take this existing code (which works) and convert it to a LINQ expression using an anonymous type as shown below:

```
var comicBook = from book in _comicBooks
                where book.Id == id
                select new
                {
                     Id = book.Id,
                     SeriesTitle = book.SeriesTitle,
                     IssueNumber = book.IssueNumber,
                     DescriptionHtml = book.DescriptionHtml,
                     Artists = book.Artists,
                     Favorite = book.Favorite
                };

return (ComicBook)comicBook;
```

However this code is returning an InvalidCastException:

```
InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'WhereSelectArrayIterator`2[ComicBooksGallery.Models.ComicBook,<>f__AnonymousType0`6[System.Int32,System.String,System.Int32,System.String,ComicBooksGallery.Models.Artist[],System.Boolean]]' to type 'ComicBooksGallery.Models.ComicBook'.
```

Am I correct in saying that my LINQ query will return a `IEnumerable<anonymous type>`? And why can I not cast this to a **ComicBook**? Also, the properties set in my anonymous type match exactly those properties found in a **ComicBook**. Shouldn't the compiler be able to infer its type without having to be explicitly cast to a **ComicBook**? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT:**

As Scott Hannen and Nkosi pointed out, I needed to select a single element from my query as it was returning a COLLECTION. Also, I needed to specify the type in my LINQ itself. The working code appears below:

```
        public ComicBook GetComicBook(int id)
        {
            //ComicBook comicBook = null;

            //foreach (var book in _comicBooks)
            //{
            //    if (book.Id == id)
            //    {
            //        comicBook = book;
            //        break;
            //    }
            //}

            // TODO:
            // convert foreach above to linq.
            // projection - project results of linq to an anonymous type.

            //var comicBook = (from book in _comicBooks
            //                 where book.Id == id
            //                 select new ComicBook
            //                 {
            //                     Id = book.Id,
            //                     SeriesTitle = book.SeriesTitle,
            //                     IssueNumber = book.IssueNumber,
            //                     DescriptionHtml = book.DescriptionHtml,
            //                     Artists = book.Artists,
            //                     Favorite = book.Favorite
            //                 }).FirstOrDefault();

            //return comicBook;

            // third times a charm.
            // one statement shouldn't have this much power ;)
            return _comicBooks.First(c => c.Id == id);
        }
```

**EDIT 2:**

As several people were kind enough to point out- this whole thing can be simplified to a single line of code with Lambda syntax!

Comment: 1) you cant convert anonymous type to ComicBook. 2) your query returns a collection and not a single comic book.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Are you saying that even if the id is unique, it will still return a collection?

Comment: to get a single result try  `var comicBook = _comicBooks.Where(book => book.Id == id).FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: That makes sense, thank you, and I think I was able to resolve this issue with adding FirstOrDefault() to my query- but the question remains: why can I not cast this to a ComicBook?

Comment: casting would imply that an anonymous type is derived from that type. Which it is not.

Comment: `why can I not cast this to a ComicBook?` Why can't you call an apple an orange? Well, basically because it isn't an orange. _The same principle applies in your code._

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linq - cast anonymous type to concrete type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28320461/linq-cast-anonymous-type-to-concrete-type)

Comment: Just use Scott Hannen's  `return _comicBooks.First(cb => cb.Id == id);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the properties you're setting - `Id`, `SeriesTitle`, etc., are all settable properties of `ComicBook` then change

```
select new
{
```

to

```
select new ComicBook
{
```

Since you're selecting a `ComicBook` by `Id` (and apparently trying to return a single `ComicBook`) you're expecting the query to return only one result. Even if that's the case, `Select` still returns a *result set* containing one item.

To get that one item from the result set, add on to the end

- `.First()` if there should always be one or more results. It throws an exception if there are no results.
- `.Single()` throws an exception unless the query returns exactly one result.
- `.FirstOrDefault()` returns the first item or null if there are no items.

---

If `_comicBooks` is a `List<ComicBook>` (or some other `IEnumerable<ComicBook>`) you could possibly even reduce the whole thing to

```
return _comicBooks.First(cb => cb.Id == id);
```

(or `FirstOrDefault` or `Single`.)

`new ComicBook` creates a new instance with the same properties as the one returned from the query. If for some reason you need to create a new instance you could do that, but you likely don't need to.

Comment: Thank you sooo much Scott! That makes perfect sense and resolved the issue for me! Cheers!